# awk to print fields that match using conditions and a default value for non-matching in two files

Tags: awk

Trying to use AWK to match the contents of each line in `file` with `$2` in `list`. Both files are tab-delimited and there may be a space or special character in the name being matched in `list`, for example in `file` the name is `BRCA1` but in `list` the name is `BRCA 1` or in `file` name is `BCR` but in `list` the name is `BCR/ABL`.

If there is a match and `$4` of `list` has `full gene sequence` in it, then `$2 and $1` are printed separated by a tab. If there is no match found then the name that was not matched and `14` are printed separated by a tab. The awk below does execute, but no output results.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
BRCA1
BCR
SCN1A
fbn1
```

**list**

```
List code   gene    gene name   methodology
81  DMD dystrophin  deletion analysis and duplication analysis
811 BRCA 1   BRCA2  full gene sequence and full deletion/duplication analysis
70  ABL1    ABL1    gene analysis variants in the kinse domane
71  BCR/ABL t(9;22) full gene sequence
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$0;next} ($2 in A){if($4=="full gene sequence"){print A[$2],$1}} ELSE {print A[$2],"14"}' file list
```

**desired output**

```
BRCA1   811
BCR 71
SCN1A   14
fbn1     85
```

**edit**

```
List code   gene    gene name   methodology
85  fbn1    Fibrillin   full gene sequencing
95  FBN1    fibrillin   del/dup
```

**result**

```
85  fbn1    Fibrillin   full gene sequencing
```

since only this line has `full gene sequencing` in it, only this is printed.

Comment: Define `match`: string or regexp? partial or full? case sensitive/insensitive? Without that info you're likely to get a solution that works for some specific test input set but then fails 6 months later on your real data. Right now you have 2 different solutions that each make very different assumptions about what you mean by `match` and will each behave differently with different input sets even though they'll produce the same output given the sample input you've provided.

Comment: match is a string that is a full and case insensitive.... that is `BRCA1` is the match but it could be `brca1` or `brca 1'. Also, I just noticed that `$4` or `full gene sequence` is not included and since there could be multiple entries for the same match, it makes it unique. I included an example in the post as well.  Thank you :).

Comment: The name in `file` will match a string in `$2` of `list`. In `list` the matching name may be part of the string, but it is always the complete name from `file`. That is the name `BCR` matches the `$2` string in `list`, `BCR/ABL`. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR==NR{
    if(NR>1){
        gsub(" ","",$2)       #removing white space
        n=split($2,v,"/")
        d[v[1]] = $1          #from split, first element as key
    } 
    next
}{print $1, ($1 in d?d[$1]:14)}' list file
```

you get,

```
BRCA1   811
BCR 71
SCN1A   14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
          a[$2]=$1;
          next
      }
     {
       for(i in a){ 
           if($1 ~ i || i ~ $1){ print $1, a[i] ; next }
       } 
        print $1,14 
     }'  list file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat list 
List code   gene    gene name   methodology
81  DMD dystrophin  deletion analysis and duplication analysis
811 BRCA 1   BRCA2  full gene sequence and full deletion/duplication analysis
70  ABL1    ABL1    gene analysis variants in the kinse domane
71  BCR/ABL t(9;22) full gene sequence

$ cat file 
BRCA1
BCR
SCN1A
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{
          a[$2]=$1;
          next
      }
     {
       for(i in a){ 
           if($1 ~ i || i ~ $1){ print $1, a[i] ; next }
       } 
        print $1,14 
     }'  list file
BRCA1 811
BCR 71
SCN1A 14
```